# Are there any best practices around being explicit between Dimension & Fact tables in a SQL Server datawarehouse?

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-warehouse

Im looking at implementing a dw in SQL Server 2008 and was wondering whether there is any distinct benefit/issue between using a simple table naming convention like dimMyTable, factMyOtherTable or using a schema for fact & dimensions.

Are there any any existing best practices around the naming/organising of fact & dimension tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't specific to data warehousing, but Brent Ozar had a post about using schemas and a great discussion took place in the comments.

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/05/why-use-schemas/

Personally, I have always used table naming conventions (i.e., fact_orders, dim_date) instead of separate schemas.

Comment: I went with the schema naming in the end, seems like it's rather a subjective thing and it seemed to fit better in the overall solution this way